# do I have to explicity dispose the transaction once I've already disposed the session?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions

I think that it's not necessary in this case (although I know we can use `using` for the transaction as well as for the session). Here is the code I'm wondering about:

```
using(var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession()){
     session.BeginTransaction();
     try {
        //some code
        session.Transaction.Commit();
     } catch(Exception ex){
        session.Transaction.Rollback();
     }
}
```

Is there any leakage for the code above? I know it would seem to be better to write it like this:

```
using(var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession()){
     using(var t = session.BeginTransaction()){
       try {
          //some code
          t.Commit();
       } catch(Exception ex){
          t.Rollback();
       }
     }
}
```

However as I said, I wonder about the necessity to dispose the transaction explicitly as well. Please advise. Btw do the above code is safe enough (using/closing right away) to use for polling data such as every second? Can it bombard with increasing opened connections to the target database? I don't think keeping a long-opening connection is good in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation here [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose?view=netframework-4.8)

> Calling this method marks the end of the transaction scope. If the TransactionScope object created the transaction and Complete was
>   called on the scope, the TransactionScope object attempts to commit
>   the transaction when this method is called. In this case, this method
>   blocks until the first phase of transaction processing is complete.
>   The first phase ends after all resource managers and enlistments in
>   the transaction have voted on the transaction outcome and the
>   TransactionManager has durably decided to commit or abort the
>   transaction. The second phase of processing is always asynchronous.
>   Therefore, there is no guarantee that data just committed from within
>   a given transaction will be immediately available afterwards when not
>   using another transaction to view this data.
>
> The use of the C# using construction ensures that this method is
>   called even if an exception occurs. Exceptions that occur after
>   calling this method may not affect the transaction. This method also
>   restores the ambient transaction to it original state. A
>   TransactionAbortedException is thrown if the transaction is not
>   actually committed.

In truth, this would be the exact same thing with having a finally clause with dispose command in it only. But you can never be sure that the next developer will not do something like this:

```
using(var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession()){
     using(var t = session.BeginTransaction()){
       try {
          //some code
          t.Commit();
       } catch(Exception ex){
          // Code the throws exception
          t.Rollback();
       } finally {
          // Some other code that throws exception
          // And then dispose
       }
     }
}
```

So instead of syntactic sugar, this also helps make sure that whatever happens everything is disposed correctly.

You can check the code here 
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Impl/

In SessionImpl.cs you will find that the code does nothing to close and/or dispose the transaction.

Comment: I'm not asking for the meaning and usage of 'using'. I meant if session is disposed will the transaction be disposed as well? So that I don't have to explicitly use 'using' on the transaction as in the second code snippet in my question. I think it's very clear about what I wonder about here

Comment: The question doesn't ask about TransactionScope though. However, I agree that there is probably not much to gain from skipping the using-statement regardless of if it is required or not.

Comment: Point in case,  both need to call the dispose implementation. Session has its own and so does transaction scope